# Count the number of months since last observation

Tags: r

My dataframe look like below:

```
ID    Date       Value  SinceLastObservation
1     1-1-2010   0      0
1     2-1-2010   0      0
1     3-1-2010   1      0
1     4-1-2010   0      1
1     5-1-2010   1      2
1     7-1-2010   0      2
1     9-1-2010   0      4
2     1-1-2011   1      0
2     2-1-2011   0      1
2     3-1-2011   0      2
2     4-1-2011   1      3
2     6-1-2011   1      2
2     8-1-2011   0      2
```

I want to add a new column (SinceLastObservation) that counts the number of months from the observations (value "1") in each group (grouped by ID) in R.

This is my solution, but it is super slow for the big data frame that I have.

```
 DT <- data.table(df)
 DT[, grp := cumsum(Value== "1")- Value, by=list(ID)]
 DT[, minDate := rollback(min(Date), preserve_hms = FALSE),by=list(ID,grp)]
 DT[, Months_since_last_1_30DPD := mondf(minDate,Date),by=list(ID,grp)]
```

mondf is a function that counts number of months between two dates

The example:

```
data <- data.frame(ID = c("1", "1", "1","1", "1", "1","1" ,"2", "2","2", "2","2", "2"), 
               Date = c("1-1-2010","2-1-2010","3-1-2010","4-1-2010","5-1-2010","7-1-2010","9-1-2010","1-1-2011","2-1-2011","3-1-2011","4-1-2011","6-1-2011","8-1-2011"), 
               value = c(0,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,0))
```

Thanks

Comment: @DanY thanks. but the date column is not sequence.

Comment: Please use `dput` to post your data in a useable form.

Comment: @MichaelDewarI just added the example.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a method using `lubridate`:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

data %>% 
  as_tibble %>% 
  mutate(Date = mdy(Date)) %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  mutate(last_obs = if_else(value==1, Date, NA_Date_),
         last_obs = lag(last_obs)) %>% 
  fill(last_obs) %>% 
  mutate(months_since_last_obs = (last_obs %--% Date)/months(1)) %>% 
  replace_na(list(months_since_last_obs = 0))
```